# Application Installer abnormal process termination(android)

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

My iphone projects run fine but while running android projects 
`(mobile sdk 2.1.1,2.1.2,2.1.3GA checked all)`. I have tried clean builds, also replaced `titanium sdk build 2.1.3` from  [appcelerator builds](http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/)  but the console gets the following exceptions

```
ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/android/builder.py", line 2282, in <module>
[ERROR]     s.run_emulator(avd_id, avd_skin, avd_name, avd_abi, add_args)
[ERROR]   File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/android/builder.py", line 567, in run_emulator
[ERROR]     handler(3,None)
[ERROR]   File "/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.1.3.GA/android/builder.py", line 552, in handler
[ERROR]     os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

I have also run configurations as trace,debug but no success

```
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
[ERROR] Timed out waiting for emulator to be ready, you may need to close the emulator and try again
```

Comment: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140526/solution-application-installer-abnormal-process-termination
Check Out this link ..

Comment: Hy Hasnain thanks for your quick response. but i am using android 2.2 which is minimum required android sdk . I am unable to run even default application in android emulator

Comment: does your emulator opens .? Android sometimes become messy sometimes on titanium. try to clean your project again. or try to remove cloud service from TiApp and then run ..

Comment: No ,emulator does not launch. I have also created AVD using android 2.3.3 package but even starting AVD ,no launcher appears

Comment: Then there might be a problem with you android sdk.

Comment: i am going to re-install  android SDK package

Comment: Thanks a lot hasnain . I re-installed android package (2.2) it give me error while setting path (no sdk home ) i created android-sdk-home folder and placed the contents (Tools.platform-tools etc folders) in it ,it worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my Question

I re-installed android package (2.2) it give me error while setting path (no sdk home ) i created android-sdk-home folder and placed the contents (Tools.platform-tools etc folders) in it ,it worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to stop all your console processes and try again.
Make sure that you have a new emulator for new android version (2.2 or 2.3)